# How to show a pdf file in a web page present on secured web hosting

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I am trying to show a pdf file in aspx page using FTP but always error 'File Not Found'
Here is my code..

```
Dim localFile As String = Server.MapPath("~/Test.pdf")
Dim URI As String = "ftp://mysitename/%2f/httpdocs/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/image123.pdf"
Dim ftp As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)

ftp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
ftp.KeepAlive = False
ftp.UseBinary = True
ftp.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

Using response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(ftp.GetResponse, System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
                Using responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
                    Using fs As New IO.FileStream(localFile, IO.FileMode.Create)
                        Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
                        Dim read As Integer = 0

                        Do
                            read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                            fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                        Loop Until read = 0

                        responseStream.Close()
                        fs.Flush()
                        fs.Close()
                    End Using
                    responseStream.Close()
                End Using
                response.Close()
            End Using

            Response.Redirect("~/Test.pdf")
```

This code runs perfectly from VS2012 because the Test.pdf file is created where the .sln file resides. But when uploaded in web hosting it shows the error that :

The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
 I also tried..

```
Dim localFile As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Test.pdf")
Dim localfile As String = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Test.pdf")
```

But all in vein..
Please help. Thanks..

Comment: No one from all over the world.. Is it impossible guys ?? If impossible then please tell some another way so that I can achieve this..

Comment: Have you FTP'd into your server to see if the file is being created?  If not, this may be a permissions issue that you need to contact your web hosting company about.  Can you upload a PDF by FTP and then download it in your browser?  Let's narrow this problem down and test each step individually.  Can you get a page to create and save a simple text file?  System.IO.File.CreateText("test.txt")

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your response and sorry for late. Files are uploading and downloading in and from the remote server successfully from Win app created in VS2008. Now I have created a web app in VS2012 which is only for reporting of the uploaded files and file should show in the browser by clicking on "Show File" in grid view.

Comment: When I run my app from Visual studio, Server.MapPath("~/Test.pdf") downloads the selected file in the path where .SLN file resides and by Response.Redirect("~/Test.pdf") it shows in the web page perfectly. Now the problem is when I upload my compiled files in remote server then Server.Mappath("~/Test.pdf") is not creating the selected file in the app path i.e. http://mysitename.in/httpdocs/webappFolder/Test.pdf. If this file would create here then all the problem gets solved. What permissions should I ask for to my web hosting company ? Please tell me....

Comment: Even when I took an Iframe, <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://mysitename/%2f/httpdocs/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/image123.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe> Then also it shows an error that "Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists". The file image123.pdf surely exists in the said path.

Comment: OK definitely sounds like a permissions problem.  First you probably want to search the FAQs or documentation that your hosting company provides.  Hopefully your hosting company has a site admin that will allow you to change permissions on certain directories in your website.  It makes sense for a hosting company that this would be turned off by default.  If all else fails, send in a support ticket.

Comment: @Jason, I made a contact to my domain admin. They say there is no problem from our side. All folders have enough permissions. You should try better coding... Now what should I do ?

Comment: I made it. The problem is solved. Not by copying the file from one folder to another but by downloading the said file as an attachment and then view it in the browser. The process is little bit slow but better late then never.. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Good to hear. I meant to respond earlier but I got caught up with a deployment.  Happy coding!